# Webcam for WPF .NET Core 3.1

Tags: wpf, .net-core, webcam, webcam-capture

I've tried a lot of dependencies in my project for webcam, including :

- [OpenCVSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCVSharp/)
- [WpfWebcamControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfWebcamControl/)
- [WebcamCapturer.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebcamCapturer.Core/)

But seems like all of those dependencies does not fully compatible with my project.

My current project dependencies :

- Microsoft.NETCore.App v3.1
- Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF

Is there any compatible webcam dependency for `WPF .NET Core v3.1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These packages are **incompatible** with .NET Core 3.1.

- [WpfWebcamControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfWebcamControl/) (>= .NET Framework 4.6)
- [WebcamCapturer.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebcamCapturer.Core/) (>= .NET Framework 4.7.2)

For OpenCV, you might be using the wrong package, as it is indeed compatible with .NET Core 3.1.

- [OpenCVSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCVSharp/) (.NET Framework)
- [OpenCVSharp4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4/) (>= .NET Framework 4.6.2, >= .NET Standard 2.0, >= .NET Core 2.1)
- For more info and packages, [see GitHub](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) and a short tutorial [here](https://www.tech-quantum.com/have-fun-with-webcam-and-opencv-in-csharp-part-1/).

Please note that the [OpenCVSharp4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4/) package is the core package, depending on your use-case, you might instead use [OpenCvSharp4.Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.Windows/) and optionally [OpenCvSharp4.WpfExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp4.WpfExtensions/). Please refer to [the project page GitHub](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) and the [Wiki](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/wiki) for more information.

Comment: do you mean that for .NET Core 3.1 I should use `OpenCVSharp4` ?

Comment: @Mark Yes. Please also see my update, there are specialized packages.

Comment: thank you. `OpenCVSharp4.Windows` and `OpenCvSharp4.WpfExtensions` work like a charm. you are my hero

Comment: I have tried using the  OpenCvSharp4.Windows and it's worked great in my pc. but it does not supporting all webcams, is there any way resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of sharing how I done it based on the accepted answer by @thatguy
first, Installing `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` and `OpenCvSharp4.WpfExtensions` into your `wpf` `.NET Core` application.

Then I put `<Image x:Name="image1" Width="400" Height="300" />` in my xaml file
and use `WriteableBitmapConverter.ToWriteableBitmap` to keep updating my image

bellow is my code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    private System.Timers.Timer MyDataTimer;
    FrameSource frameSource = Cv2.CreateFrameSource_Camera(0);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyDataTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        MyDataTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyDataTimer_Elapsed);
        MyDataTimer.Enabled = true;

        MyDataTimer.Interval = 1 * 1;    
        MyDataTimer.Start();
    }
    private void MyDataTimer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            MyDataTimer.Stop();
            MyDataTimer.Interval = 1 * 1;
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(LoadImages));
            MyDataTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            MyDataTimer.Start();
        }
    }
    private void LoadImages()
    {
        using (var mat = new Mat())
        {
            frameSource.NextFrame(mat);

            var wb = WriteableBitmapConverter.ToWriteableBitmap(mat);
            image1.Source = null;
            image1.Source = wb;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this would help!